# How add a column to the front of np array?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I want to add a column `x0` of `shape(1,10)` to the front of an existing nparray `X` of `shape(10,3)` so that the final np array `X_new` becomes of the `shape (10,4)`.

```
x0 = np.ones((1,np.shape(X)[0]))
X = np.array([[1500,1,2],[1700,3,3],[2000,2,2],[2400,2,3],[2700,3,3],[3000,3,4],[3100,2,3],[3300,3,4],[3500,4,5],[3600,3,4]])
```

output:

```
X_new = np.array([[1,1500,1,2],[1,1700,3,3],[1,2000,2,2],[1,2400,2,3],[1,2700,3,3],[1,3000,3,4],[1,3100,2,3],[1,3300,3,4],[1,3500,4,5],[1,3600,3,4]])
```

I have tried doing concatenation, hstack but I am not able to get the desired resultant np array.

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: You really should tell us what was wrong with the things you tried.  If it runs, but you don't like the result, show that and say what was wrong.  If an error, show that.  Most likely you got a message about wrong dimensions.  Do you understand array dimensions?

Comment: What output do you get instead?

Comment: Sorry for not putting the output. I was getting error that showed that the dimensional values are not matching. The answer below solved the problem. Next time I'll keep in mind to show the errors. Thank you, everyone, for the help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong shape for `x0`, once you modify that, you can use `np.hstack`:

```
X = np.array([[1500,1,2],[1700,3,3],[2000,2,2],[2400,2,3],[2700,3,3],[3000,3,4],[3100,2,3],[3300,3,4],[3500,4,5],[3600,3,4]])
x0 = np.ones((np.shape(X)[0],1))

x_new = np.hstack([x0,X])
x_new

array([[1, 1500, 1, 2],
       [1, 1700, 3, 3],
       [1, 2000, 2, 2],
       [1, 2400, 2, 3],
       [1, 2700, 3, 3],
       [1, 3000, 3, 4],
       [1, 3100, 2, 3],
       [1, 3300, 3, 4],
       [1, 3500, 4, 5],
       [1, 3600, 3, 4]])
```